# In MYSQL can I disable for anyone and everyone the drop table (or a DB) query?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I would like to totally disable anyone from dropping a table or DB from MYSQL using a query / injection. I have just started to read about users and permissions, as far as Im aware I have never created any users. I have no need to drop any tables at all. Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't created any users, the only user is the `root` user, and it has to be allowed to do anything.

Comment: When you create users, you can give them all permissions except `DROP TABLE` and `DROP DATABASE`. But you have to list all the permissions explicitly, there's no way to say "Everything except ..."

Comment: thanks:) If I create another user will the root user still exist? Could I then grant root certain permissions?

Comment: Yes, root user still exists unless you delete it, but you generally shouldn't do that.

Comment: You should always have the root user, since users with limited privileges will not be able to do emergency maintenance.

Comment: Okay thankyou very much